# Updating Firefox via pop-up prompt?

Tags: updates, firefox

Firefox is prompting me for an update. I am used to a Windows environment, so is this the same thing? If I accept, it will simply update and I don't need to worry about a thing?

I worry if Firefox knows the update is a Linux update and not a Windows one?

Also, can you make your answer applicable to Debian as well as Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is rather vague as is. May be you could add more details, a screenshot of the promp, so we get an idea of what happens.

Comment: "it depends" , how did you install firefox ? Normally you install it with apt-get or from software manager. Linux is not windows and you manage software slightly differently. Rather then finding software on the web and running installers, you use apt , see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftwareManagement

Comment: In this case, I downloaded the file from the Firefox website, a tar I believe, and unpacked it in a readymade folder. It works fine. I will try to post a snapshot when it pops up, but it is simply Firefox's own prompt asking me for the update.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry.

This is a Linux update for Firefox.

Firefox behaves the same as in Windows but for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu (and Debian) uses a package management system. Normally, you don't download and install software like you did in Windows, but use this package management system instead.

You can run the Ubuntu Software Center from the menu to see all updates, or run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

from the terminal.

Comment: Thanks, but see my above comment on how I installed it.